# What does the git error message "Server does not allow request for unadvertised object" mean?

Tags: git, github

I am trying to do a checkout from github, and I got this error message:

```
[user@arch ~]$ git clone --recursive https://github.com/simsong/tcpflow.git
Cloning into 'tcpflow'...
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.253.113)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.253.113' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
remote: Counting objects: 4190, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (32/32), done.
remote: Total 4190 (delta 21), reused 29 (delta 12), pack-reused 4146
Receiving objects: 100% (4190/4190), 50.27 MiB | 2.21 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2954/2954), done.
Submodule 'src/be13_api' (https://github.com/simsong/be13_api.git) registered for path 'src/be13_api'
Submodule 'src/dfxml' (https://github.com/simsong/dfxml.git) registered for path 'src/dfxml'
Submodule 'src/http-parser' (https://github.com/nodejs/http-parser.git) registered for path 'src/http-parser'
Cloning into '/home/user/tcpflow/src/be13_api'...
remote: Counting objects: 1203, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
remote: Total 1203 (delta 2), reused 5 (delta 1), pack-reused 1194
Receiving objects: 100% (1203/1203), 477.47 KiB | 1.96 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (821/821), done.
Cloning into '/home/user/tcpflow/src/dfxml'...
remote: Counting objects: 1929, done.
remote: Total 1929 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 1929
Receiving objects: 100% (1929/1929), 572.09 KiB | 2.89 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1294/1294), done.
Cloning into '/home/user/tcpflow/src/http-parser'...
remote: Counting objects: 1487, done.
remote: Total 1487 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 1487
Receiving objects: 100% (1487/1487), 667.24 KiB | 2.46 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (916/916), done.
Submodule path 'src/be13_api': checked out 'c81521d768bb78499c069fcd7c47adc8eee0350c'
Submodule path 'src/dfxml': checked out 'c31224626cf5f6678d42cbcfbfcd4e6191c9a864'
error: Server does not allow request for unadvertised object 5bbcdc5df9d01b521e8da011bab0da70bdec3653
Fetched in submodule path 'src/http-parser', but it did not contain 5bbcdc5df9d01b521e8da011bab0da70bdec3653. Direct fetching of that commit failed.
[user@arch ~]$
```

So I'm the maintainer of these repos. The src/http-parser is a fork of another repo, and the maintainers of that repo have consistently not accepted my pull requests (with no reasons given) to add a few auto-generated files to the `.gitignore` file. But I don't think that's the issue here.

Comment: I've tried the same command and there was no error. Do you still have an issue?
Btw in my case it checked out different commit: `Submodule path 'src/http-parser': checked out '6b05cce82da5c4d407e5576ab892bc20a17b0394'`

Comment: The issue is gone. I think that it means that the submodule reference was for a checkout that doesn't exist. But Im' not sure.

Comment: As a note for others confused but this message, it can arise if you update a submodule, update a parent module to the new commit, and never push the new commit in the submodule. Then, of course, you'll have trouble checking out a commit that doesn't exist on the submodule's remote!

Comment: The problem seems to be that I updated the submodule, updated the parent repo, pushed the parent repo, but didn't push the submodule. So literally, the parent repo referenced a commit that wasn't in the submodule's repo on github.

Answer (score 18):

[jgit - What is git's advertised refs? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485966/what-is-gits-advertised-refs):

> During a fetch, the server can list references that it has and that the client may wish to fetch. These are the advertised references.

- It looks like **you cannot directly get any single specific commit from the server, only refs (i.e. branches and tags).** Or rather, that Github servers are configured to disallow such requests.
- So, **if you want to get a specific commit with [`--depth`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#git-submodule---depth), it must be at most `<depth>-1` commits away from the fetched ref** (which is the branch/tag specified in the submodule's metadata)

  <sub>Typically, folks advise to just set `depth` to some number reasonably large but still much smaller than the total number of commit in the repo -- like `50` or `100`. E.g. `50` is what Travis uses when doing the initial clone for the project.</sub>

If you aren't updating the submodule with `--depth`, failing to find the commit would mean any of:

- the submodule's tree is in "shallow" state and the above applies (only possible when it was previously updated with `--depth` or [its entry in `.gitmodules` has `shallow = true`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitmodules#gitmodules-submoduleltnamegtshallow))
- the commit is not on the branch that the submodule is using
- the commit is not in the submodule's repo at all:

  - either someone made a mistake,
  - or it was once there but was deleted by a forced push

---

For the record, in your specific case, it was the last case: commit `5bbcdc5df9d01b521e8da011bab0da70bdec3653` is not in the `https://github.com/simsong/http-parser.git` repo at all.

Comment: What is `depth`?

Comment: @vy32 added info for the case when you aren't updating with `--depth`.

Comment: "it was once there but was deleted by a forced push" - is there any recourse in this situation?

Comment: @skolsuper choose a different commit to retrieve. E.g. if that was a submodule, switch it to a different commit in the superproject.

Answer (score 10):

One way to get access to an unadvertized object is to sync. Then a submodule update should work, like:

```
git submodule sync --recursive
git submodule update
```

Comment: For potentially large super-projects, you'd be advised to actually carry out `$ git submodule sync --recursive; git submodule update` OR, if it is just after cloning a remote , just `$ git submodule update --init --recursive`. This will effectively traverse your project file-tree from `/project/root/` down, according to what's in `/project/root/.gitmodules`.  Much more at `$ git submodule --help`...

Comment: In my case, someone had actually pushed a submodule with a detached head, which caused this error.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen when you are pointing to submodule commit that has been removed through a history re-write or squash.  The best you can do is:

- First get a clear picture of what your team has been doing so you know what it should look like.
- Update your local with a git pull and then find the closest commit that works with your branch (it may be the latest) and then add that to your parent repo. e.g. something like:

```
parent-repo$ git fetch
parent-repo$ cd submodule-a
submodule-a$ git pull
submodule-a$ git checkout best-commit-according-to-team-and-your-branch
submodule-a$ cd ../
parent-repo$ git status
...
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
        modified:  submodule-a (modified content)
...
git add submodule-a
git commit -m "updated submodule-a reference"
```

Once you are happy it is correct and your team agrees you can push it up and the error should go away.

Answer (score 1):

When I run:

```
git submodule update
```

or

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

I got the error:

> error: Server does not allow request for unadvertised object xxxxxxxxx
>
> Fetched in submodule path 'xxx', but it did not contain
> xxxxxxxxx.Direct fetching of that commit failed.

And **I fixed this problem by** :

```
git submodule update --remote
```

Comment: git submodule update --remote: But that will checkout the latest commit on the branch of the submodule project?

Answer (score 0):

For me, this tends to happen when I push a parent git repo back to github without pushing back a sub-module that I've modified and committed, but haven't pushed back.