# Strange git fetch/pull after update

Tags: git

I've update my Git and get some interesting errors like this one:

```
error: Server does not allow request for unadvertised object e7369c9b3741a15235ad6d960c026607cbff96ea
```

I have it on Git 2.21.0+ (2.20.1 works fine) on MacOS and Windows, errors only on submodule which is on Stash Server - main repo just has everything as a submodules.

Steps to reproduce:

1. `git clone $main_repo`
2. `cd $main_repo`
3. `git remove origin`
4. `git add origin $main_repo`
5. `git fetch --all --prune` - or pull, doesn't matter

Another strange thing: if I'll go to failed submodule and do same steps  here - everything will be fine.

I don't understand is it a bug in Git or something wrong with my company Stash.

Any help to how to explore it deeper?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the git error message "Server does not allow request for unadvertised object" mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/1240216/what-does-the-git-error-message-server-does-not-allow-request-for-unadvertised)

Comment: Don't think so - I don't have this error while cloning, and I have this error only on specific git version

Comment: Cloning the main repo will not fetch on the submodules. When you fetch the submodule, apparently the main repo references a commit that does not exist in the submodule. See the list "If you aren't…" in the linked answer. But it may be Git bug as well? (I got the same error today, ironically, but didn't have time to follow up on it.)

Comment: `git clone --recursive $main_repo` works too, will it be enough to check?
Submodules doesn't have `shallow=true`, only `path`,  `url` and `branch` (`master` for failed submodule).